# Combining `by lazy` and `object` results in compiler-error "cannot find symbol"

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, kapt

I cannot compile anymore after the update to Kotlin 1.3.0 (**works in 1.2.71**) when trying to use `by lazy` **and** `object`. This seems to happen only on my project. A demo-project is working fine.

I want to add an interface to a given class and lazy-load its values.

I've created a small example which is *not working in my project* but *working fine in any other*:

```
open class Foo

interface Bar {
    val lazyLoadedString : String
}

class Test {
    private val foo by lazy {
        object : Foo(), Bar {
            override val lazyLoadedString  = "Demo"
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I combine `object` and `by lazy`, it cannot compile anymore and shows the following error. Using each one alone works.

> Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
>   private final my.package.Test$foo$2$1 getFoo()
>
> symbol: class Test$foo$2$1
>   location: package my.package

When looking closer, you'll see that **the generated java file** shows this error and not the kotlin-code.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: This originates from an issue for the groupie library but I think it's not the library causing this. See https://github.com/lisawray/groupie/issues/218

Comment: Turns out, I'm using the gradle-plugins `kotlin-kapt` and `realm-android` and these two combined cause this. My demo-project (https://github.com/hardysim/bylazy-demo) does not compile in the current state and starts working when you remove either kotlin-kapt or realm-android.

Comment: Could be a bug in Javassist, tbh

Comment: There's now a issue at the realm-repo as well: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like kapt is broken in Kotlin 1.3.0 for this particular kind of code.

In the code above, it was the annotation processor registered by Realm that triggered it, but any other annotation processor would have resulted in the same error.

The issue is being tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-28053

Comment: Correct. I forgot to close this here. I was able to workaround this by specifying the type explicitly. Plus, it should be fixed in Kotlin 1.3.20.