# Best alternative for object keyword in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 private val timer = object : CountDownTimer(result, 1000) {
    override fun onFinish() {
        //delete the database entry
    }

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        //more code

    }

}
```

As far as my knowledge in kotlin, object gets called before the `result` gets assigned a value

Initially, the `result` value is 0, then it gets updated in another function, but the timer gets called with `result` value as 0.

So what should be the best replacement for `object` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep `object`, you just need to change order of initialization. One way would be to use `by lazy`, like this:

```
    var result = 0L

    private val timer: CountDownTimer by lazy {
        object : CountDownTimer(result, 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() {
                // delete the database entry
            }

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                // more code
            }
        }
    }

    // 'init' block just as an example; the below code works anywhere
    // such as in onCreate(), onStart() or wherever
    init {
        result = 1000
        // 'timer' is initialized with result=1000 and then started
        timer.start()
    }
```

`lazy` is a so called property delegate, you can read more about it in the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) for example.

Comment: Now I get compilation error, error: cannot find symbol

  symbol:   class <Classname>$timer$2$1

Works with android?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. If that doesn't help, I advice you to ask a new question on this site with the details of your build system, its configuration, and the exact code you have problems with.

Comment: this particular code gives the error - I don't even call it yet

Comment: This is the error -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53168385/combining-by-lazy-and-object-results-in-compiler-error-cannot-find-symbol


 A workaround is to specify the type explicitly. A workaround is to specify the type of foo explicitly.

Now how do we do this in my case?

Comment: Nice that you found the reason for the error! I have update my answer to specify the type of `timer` (not `foo` in your case) explicitly as specified in the issue you linked to. Can I get my upvote back now please? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is related to Kotlin?

- You have a member val: timer
- It is initialized when the object, the val resides in, is created.

So the problem is not what syntax you are using. It is the time you create timer. If you know when you are going to use it, and you are sure that by this time the result will be intialized, you can use lazy initialization.